# Stacking divs from the bottom right

Tags: css

I am adding colour blocks (divs with bg colours) to a parent div. Each parent div can have a number of these colour blocks which are to display  in the bottom right of the parent, with a maximum of three to a row.

My code (below) does what is required for 3 or less colours, but if a forth colour is added it jumps to the line below leaving two empty spaces on the bottom line. What I would like to happen is for the forth colour to be displayed on the line above so the bottom line has no blanks.

You can see the problem in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/adLLv36L/5/) along with a hardcoded example of what I would like to happen.

```
<style>
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 142px;
}

.colorSwatches {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   max-width: 100px;
   max-height:60px;
   text-align:right
}

.swatch {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    margin: 2px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);  ///or whatever
}
</style>


<div class="container">
  <div class="colorSwatches">
     <div class="swatch"></div>
     <div class="swatch"></div>
     <div class="swatch"></div>
     <div class="swatch"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can pull off that layout with some **flexbox** magic:

- set your `.swatches` container, in your case `.colorSwatches`, with `display: flex` prop
- then to this container and a `flex-wrap` rule of: `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse`, so that the children inside it will wrap, on to the next line, in opposite direction of the `flex-direction`, which by default is `row` I think.
- and lastly, add to the container, the `justify-content: flex-end;` so that the items inside will start laying out at the end of their container.

Here's a [**jsfiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/8ekcq44g/3/) and a couple of resources:

- [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/)
- [Justify-content](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/)
- [Flex-wrap](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/)

Comment: A perfect solution. Thanks for your help.